# change connection string for dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

How to create authentication window for database when I use dataset - MyDatabaseDataSet?

When I didn't use dataset I simply open new SqlConnection for every operation and use some connection string which was created after I writed Login and Password. But Dataset use some default connection string. How to change it?

I want to connect to database and tables with connection string `Data Source=XXXX-PC\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID={0};Password={1}` where {0} and {1} - parameters from authentication window.

I don't understand where to put my connection string and then use it as default connection string.

Comment: This should be in your web.config

Comment: Can you post the code for creating your SqlConnection? SqlConnection has a constructor for a connection string.

Comment: @AntLaC if he is distributing his executable, he might not want everyone seeing the password to his db.

Comment: @JoshC. I didn't know if this was a web app or not

Comment: it is windows forms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems in the past with DataSet objects using a default connection string.

To get around this, I pass the connection string into my SqlConnection constructor.

In my case I'm using a web.config to hold the connection string.

```
var dt1 = new CustomDataSet.CustomDataTable();
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var da1 = new GetCustomDataTableAdapter() { Connection = connection })
    {
        da1.Fill(dt1, id);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I've got only App.Config. And there is `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectToDatabase.Properties.Settings.MyDatabaseConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=XXXX-PC\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: But I don't know how to pass login and password there. Maybe create some parameters there and pass it from authentication dialog?

Comment: I know what connection string to use. I don't know how to pass paramater to connection string in app.confgi

Comment: @user1432980 you don't pass the parameters to your config. From my example above, you can see I create a string variable called connectionString. Use string.Format() to create a new string with your login and password. Then pass it to the SqlConnection.

Comment: But you get connection string from connectionStringName object in ConnectionString collection

Comment: @user1432980 right, but after you get the connection string, you can then manipulate it to include the login and password before passing it to the constructor of your SqlConnection.